# Is there a performance advantage to mounting a volume as readonly?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-pvc, kubernetes-deployment, mounted-volumes

In Kubernetes deployments, you can specify volume mounts as readonly. Is there a performance advantage to it, or logical only?

Is it dependant on the volume type?

To make my intentions clear, I'm using a pv in a scenario where I have one writer and many readers, and noticed any fs operation on the mounted volume is much slower than on the volatile disk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It entirely depends on the volume type. Some might implement performance optimizations when they know the volume is read only.

Comment: Do you have any reference or pointers to these? As you can guess I searched and didn't find any mention of such optimizations

Comment: Kubernetes is just passing the flag down into the underlying system. I know some iscsi devices have a specific read-only lun modes that bypass the write cache. GCP disks also specifically recognize read-only mode and I would imagine they do a similar trick there.